Make Maven ignore error when deploying submodules
I am trying to deploy a Maven project to a package repository right now, and I am afraid that my current setup will not actually work for this purpose.
I have a project that is a collection of libraries. Each module of the library is a separate Maven Artifact to allow me to load only the necessary modules when using this library.
The project structure is as follows:
Project A (Parent, no code just common POM config)
|
- - Project B (one library module)
|
- - Project C (Parent POM for closely related sub-modules, inheriting from Project A still)
  |
  - Project D (one library module)
  |
  - Project E (one library module)

I have fixed a bug in Project "E" and I want to push an updated version (1.0.1) to a repository that already contains version 1.0.0 of all projects. If I run deploy on the root, Project A deployment will fail, because the repository I am pushing to does not allow deploying the same version twice. However, Maven will promptly skip all other sub-modules, even if --fail-at-end (to be precise, I am writing the shorthand -fae is provided through the CLI. The result is the following:
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Project A 1.0.0 ..................................... FAILURE [  1.540 s]
[INFO] Project B 1.0.0 ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Project C 1.0.0 ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Project D 1.0.0 ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Project E 1.0.1 ..................................... SKIPPED

Is there any way to force Maven to attempt deployment of sub-modules even if parent fails?
I would expect that deployment of projects A-D fail, but Project E, having a version unavailable in the remote repository goes through, essentially, with -fae I am expecting the following:
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Project A 1.0.0 ..................................... FAILURE [  1.540 s]
[INFO] Project B 1.0.0 ..................................... FAILURE [  X s]
[INFO] Project C 1.0.0 ..................................... FAILURE [  X s]
[INFO] Project D 1.0.0 ..................................... FAILURE [  X s]
[INFO] Project E 1.0.1 ..................................... SUCCESS [  X s]

Is this possible? In the simplified example I am giving there's only one package that has changed but in the real scenario I have multiple, and I would dread having to go through every single package deploying the specific sub-module manually every time I have to push a new version or fix.

You need a new version of each submodules. Your fix won't be referenced otherwise

@JustanotherJavaprogrammer The project that has been fixed isn't a dependency to any other module in the library (it however, uses other modules). So any project using E should just update to the fixed version, the other modules are unaffected and can be used in their current version.

The general Idea of a multi module build is that the version for all modules is the same... technically you can change a single module. My assumption is that the failure is based on blocking of your repository manager which does not allow to redeploy already released versions...

@khmarbaise That is simply not true, there is no implicit or explicit recommendation that a multi-module Maven build has all the same version.

@khmarbaise The failure is indeed the repository rejecting the deployment of an already present version. What I don't understand is why even with the -fae parameter, Maven skips the subsequent projects instead of attempting. I know (and don't want to) I can't deploy the same version twice, I just want it to push all, fail on duplicates and push changes. I am asking for how to do this because Maven -fae parameter isn't achieving that I am having a hard time figuring it out

Maven is heavily opinionated about how the world should be and it may be an uphill battle to make it work well otherwise.

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Then what should I do instead? Have these all be separate projects? Use a script to deploy each submodule individually?

If you insist on doing it this way with -fae then file a bug report on maven so they either fix it or help you.

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I am not really insisting in doing it any way, I just want my project to work, I am willing and it wouldn't be the first time I change its structure, but no one here has provided any advice beyond "just don't"

Tell maven only to process the module you have actually changed - read up on the command line arguments. Or consider having a build robot do it for you.  Or have the repository owner change it so you can redeploy.  This may be an X-Y problem.

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen a script it is then, just have it automatically build all of the modules instead of just the parent. Thanks!

If you need to deploy only some of the projects, simply do
mvn deploy --projects :project-e,:project-f

Any configuration from root pom is applied, but only selected projects are being built and deployed.
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] project-e 1.0-SNAPSHOT .............................. SUCCESS [  0.479 s]
[INFO] project-f 1.1-SNAPSHOT .............................. SUCCESS [  0.025 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------


This is a bad option, because this means I have to remember all the projects that have been changed at any moment when I want to deploy. My parent POMs rarely change so I end up with a lot of children that can potentially change, but no way to just deploy all changed modules

I'm baffled. Of course you have to remember which projects have been updated. If they are not sharing the same version, they are independent of one another anyway, and their releases are separate. But that aside, are you keeping your poms of already released projects at the correct version? They should be at the next SNAPSHOT, not the release version. Having it that way solves the problem for you. May want to add -Dmaven.deploy.skip=snapshots to the build command.

Well, the process to update a project that I use is as follows, go into POM and increment version, go into the project and do changes, commit. Since the library exists for projects, I tend to not do releases until I know the library does all i want it to do for the separate project I am using it in, which my IDE will keep synced by compiling all dependencies on the go as I make changes. Once the project/sprint is done, the next library version is released, at this point, many projects have been changed, but the parent POMs haven't, so the updated children get skipped.
